# Filtering CoreData result - List (UI) not update according to the filtered result

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have my data using CoreData. I added a searchBar for filtering the CoreData records in the List.

```
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)

private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
@State var searchText: String = "" // get the search string from search bar
```

Here is the code for filtering the data:

```
var filteredItems: [Item] {
    let list = Array(Set(itemsFilteredByText))
    print(list) // here print the right number of items according to the text in searchText
    return list
}


var itemsFilteredByText: [Item] {
    
    items.filter {
        (item) -> Bool in
        (self.searchText.isEmpty || self.searchText == "" ) ? true :
            item.name.contains(self.searchText.lowercased())        
        )
    }
}
```

In my list, it is like this:

```
List {
    ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
        Text("\(item.name)")
    }
}
```

Whenever I typed in the search bar, sometimes it display correctly, sometimes, it only display part of the result. The UI did not update appropriately but the filtered function works.

** Some Update **
I have tried to update according to the suggested solution by @Sreekuttan. The filteredItems show proper result. Yet, the UI still not refresh and showing the old list (e.g., after filtering, there are 1 item in filteredItem, however, the List still shows 3 items)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the views with the search bar text, you must set the *filteredItems* as a State variable. Each time the text in the search bar changes assigns the filtered results to the *filteredItems*. it will update your List view accordingly.

```
import Combine
```

Define your Property wrappers

```
@State var searchText: String = ""
@State private var filteredItems: [Item] = []
```

.onReceive will be called each time text changes

```
    TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
        .onReceive(Just(searchText)) { searchText in
            print(searchText)
            
            // update filteredItems
            filteredItems = Array(Set(itemsFilteredByText))
        }
```

Comment: From my code above, where should i call the function? indeed, when searchText has been changed, now it will call itemsFilteredByText automatically. I printed the result and find that it can do filtering properly, but it cannot update the UI

Comment: It also says: "Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property"

Comment: I just changed the code so that you will have a better understanding.

Comment: I understand your code. Thank you. However, it does not really resolve my problem. I think that my problem comes from @FetchRequest, the UI did not update fast enough to show the updated list. I used print() after your "filteredItems = Array(Set(itemsFilteredByText))", it print the correct filteredItems. However, the List() did not shows all the items. Some of the items are missing.

Comment: Your List view updates only when you set filteredItems in a @State Property wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I have printed the filteredItems, it has been updated, but the UI not refresh... :( I use your code exactly...

Answer (score 0):

you could use predicate to filter results

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Setting.entity(), sortDescriptors: [] , predicate: NSPredicate(format: "item.name == \(searchText)"))
```

Comment: In my case, I need to take the entity id to my model to get the appropriate item, and the search text filter those items instead, so i cannot directly apply predicate here to my entity.

Answer (score 0):

It is found that I have used .animation() in my List{}. Frequent list sorting / filtering caused the animation cannot be completed, hence not refreshing the UI. Hope this may give some help to people who may experience the same.